# Prevent prerequisites from requesting restart, setup.exe setup project bootstrapper

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

Is there a way to prevent prerequisites -for example some redistributable for C++- from requesting reboot using some command line argument passed to `setup.exe` file or something like that? I have tried `/NOREBOOT`, `/NORESTART` but they haven't worked.

**EDIT**

The exact prerequisite causing the problem for me is: `vcredist_2008_x86.exe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .Net boot strapper if the excecuted process exited a specific codes tells that it need reboot, its usually not preferred to ignore this because it may make a serious or important changes that will not take affects till you reboot.

First of all you need to check what is the exit code that your process exit with, go to setup log (usually located on `%temp%\VS####.tmp`) and look for

```
Process exited with code ###
```

For me the process exited with `3010` code.

After that you need to modify the package's `product.xml` file to make the setup ignore that exit code by adding the follwing to the `ExitCodes` node:

```
<ExitCode Value="3010" Result="Success" />
```

So the final `product.xml` file content should be looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product ProductCode="Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="vcredist_x86.exe" PublicKey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
  </PackageFiles>
  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="IsInstalled" Product="{FF66E9F6-83E7-3A3E-AF14-8DE9A809A6A4}" />
  </InstallChecks>
  <Commands Reboot="None">
    <Command PackageFile="vcredist_x86.exe" Arguments="/q">
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThan" Value="0" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="Success" />
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Success" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

If you are using `Bootstrapper Manifest Generator`, you may simply add the `3010` exit code and set the result to be 'Success':
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use command line for Visual C++ 2008 redistributable packages (vcredist_x86.exe, vcredist_x64.exe and vcredist_ia64.exe) as

For example, if you download vcredist_x86.exe to a folder named c:\vc2008redist, then the command line would look like this:

> c:\vc2008redist\vcredist_x86.exe /q /norestart

The example above use the /norestart switch to suppress reboots after the setup process completes.  The /norestart switch does not eliminate the need to reboot entirely – it just gives the calling process control over when to schedule the reboot if one is needed due to files being in use during setup.  If you running setup with the /norestart switch, you must check the exit code returned by the setup process and handle it accordingly in the calling process.  Here are the possible exit codes:

> - Exit code 0 means that setup succeeded and no reboot is needed.
> - Exit code 3010 means that setup succeeded and a reboot is needed to complete installation.
> - Any other exit code means that setup failed.
>
> Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/10/20/10078468.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you run the vcredist exe with a /? argument it shows a message box with the options. It lists /norestart in lowercase, it may be case sensitive.

Comment: The exact prerequisite causing the problem for me is: vcredist_2008_x86.exe, and this has no (norestart) option at all :(

Answer (score 0):

If the executable doesn't provide a command line argument I don't believe you can do it directly. You can always use the WIN API through c# to intercept the Shut down/reboot messages.

[Catch Shutdown event with example code](http://hintdesk.com/c-catch-shutdown-event-of-computer/)

[System Shutdown Functions (AbortSystemShutdown function)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)